# Tracking events in Universal Analytics only partly working

Tags: events, analytics, tracking

Currently using Universal Analytics on my website that's already tracking PDF downloads and I'm trying to implement this for a video as well, to see how many times this video has been played.

```
<p><iframe width="482" height="271" src="video URL" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'videos', 'play', 'eco-assistant', '10');"></iframe></p>
```

This is the actual [page](http://www.dnv.com/industry/maritime/servicessolutions/consulting/solutions/ECOAssistant_4/).

Any idea why video plays are not tracked?

Many thanks,
B.

Comment: The video is within an iframe, and unless you control the code within the iframe, you won't be able to access or add Google Analytics tracking directly. Is there an API for that video player you can work with which would allow you add your GA tracking?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to keep in mind is that the value attributed to the event should be an integer, not a string. Your onClick code should be the following:

onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'videos', 'play', 'eco-assistant', 10);"

Hope this additional information is helpful.

B. Keller